# How to make an AngularJs ng-options with subitems

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-options, subitem

I'd like to put the json returned logins into a ng-options.
The problem is the login and other attributes like id, url etc is as subitem of 
How can i Make an Angular ng-options with its values?

The Html

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
...
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController">
       <select ng-options="l as list.items.login for l in lists"
            ng-model="item" ng-change="update()"></select>
... </html>
```

MainController.js ($scope.list IS returning the Json below)

```
...
var onUserComplete = function (response) {
        $scope.list = response.data;
...
```

I 
Json returned

```
{
      "total_count": 4,
      "incomplete_results": false,
      "items": [
        {
          "login": "mojombo",
          "id": 1,
          "avatar_url": "https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/1?v=3",
          "gravatar_id": "",
          "url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo",
          "html_url": "https://github.com/mojombo",
          "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/followers",
          "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/following{/other_user}",
          "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/gists{/gist_id}",
          "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
          "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/subscriptions",
          "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/orgs",
          "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/repos",
          "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/events{/privacy}",
          "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/received_events",
          "type": "User",
          "site_admin": false,
          "score": 49.54566
        },
        {
          "login": "tomdale",
          "id": 90888,
          "avatar_url": "https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/90888?v=3",
          "gravatar_id": "",
          "url": "https://api.github.com/users/tomdale",
          "html_url": "https://github.com/tomdale",
          "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tomdale/followers",
          "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tomdale/following{/other_user}",
          "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tomdale/gists{/gist_id}",
          "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tomdale/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
          "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tomdale/subscriptions",
          "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tomdale/orgs",
          "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tomdale/repos",
          "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tomdale/events{/privacy}",
          "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tomdale/received_events",
          "type": "User",
          "site_admin": false,
          "score": 40.39779
        },
        {
          "login": "tmcw",
          "id": 32314,
          "avatar_url": "https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/32314?v=3",
          "gravatar_id": "",
          "url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmcw",
          "html_url": "https://github.com/tmcw",
          "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmcw/followers",
          "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmcw/following{/other_user}",
          "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmcw/gists{/gist_id}",
          "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmcw/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
          "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmcw/subscriptions",
          "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmcw/orgs",
          "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmcw/repos",
          "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmcw/events{/privacy}",
          "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmcw/received_events",
          "type": "User",
          "site_admin": false,
          "score": 36.811348
        },
        {
          "login": "tommy351",
          "id": 411425,
          "avatar_url": "https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/411425?v=3",
          "gravatar_id": "",
          "url": "https://api.github.com/users/tommy351",
          "html_url": "https://github.com/tommy351",
          "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tommy351/followers",
          "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tommy351/following{/other_user}",
          "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tommy351/gists{/gist_id}",
          "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tommy351/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
          "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tommy351/subscriptions",
          "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tommy351/orgs",
          "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tommy351/repos",
          "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tommy351/events{/privacy}",
          "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tommy351/received_events",
          "type": "User",
          "site_admin": false,
          "score": 15.513104
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by *"subitem"*? Do you mean like an [`<optgroup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup)?

Comment: "login": "mojombo",

Comment: That literally tells me nothing. Why don't you give an example of what the resulting HTML should look like, ie `<select><!-- what do you want here --></select>`

Comment: id like to make an OPTION using angular ng-options like:   <select>
    <option>mojombo</option>
    <option>tomdale</option>
    ...
 </select>

Comment: So just use `ng-options="login.login for login in lists"`

Comment: didnt work!                         <select ng-options="login.login for login in lists"
                                ng-model="item" ng-change="update()"></select>

Comment: Sorry, should have been `in lists.items`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one , u can select items based on login name

```js
var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('myCrtl',function($scope){

$scope.data={
      "total_count": 4,
      "incomplete_results": false,
      "items": [
        {
          "login": "mojombo",
          "id": 1,
          "avatar_url": "https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/1?v=3",
          "gravatar_id": "",
          "url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo",
          "html_url": "https://github.com/mojombo",
          "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/followers",
          "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/following{/other_user}",
          "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/gists{/gist_id}",
          "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
          "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/subscriptions",
          "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/orgs",
          "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/repos",
          "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/events{/privacy}",
          "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/received_events",
          "type": "User",
          "site_admin": false,
          "score": 49.54566
        },
        {
          "login": "tomdale",
          "id": 90888,
          "avatar_url": "https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/90888?v=3",
          "gravatar_id": "",
          "url": "https://api.github.com/users/tomdale",
          "html_url": "https://github.com/tomdale",
          "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tomdale/followers",
          "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tomdale/following{/other_user}",
          "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tomdale/gists{/gist_id}",
          "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tomdale/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
          "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tomdale/subscriptions",
          "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tomdale/orgs",
          "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tomdale/repos",
          "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tomdale/events{/privacy}",
          "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tomdale/received_events",
          "type": "User",
          "site_admin": false,
          "score": 40.39779
        },
        {
          "login": "tmcw",
          "id": 32314,
          "avatar_url": "https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/32314?v=3",
          "gravatar_id": "",
          "url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmcw",
          "html_url": "https://github.com/tmcw",
          "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmcw/followers",
          "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmcw/following{/other_user}",
          "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmcw/gists{/gist_id}",
          "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmcw/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
          "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmcw/subscriptions",
          "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmcw/orgs",
          "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmcw/repos",
          "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmcw/events{/privacy}",
          "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmcw/received_events",
          "type": "User",
          "site_admin": false,
          "score": 36.811348
        },
        {
          "login": "tommy351",
          "id": 411425,
          "avatar_url": "https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/411425?v=3",
          "gravatar_id": "",
          "url": "https://api.github.com/users/tommy351",
          "html_url": "https://github.com/tommy351",
          "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tommy351/followers",
          "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tommy351/following{/other_user}",
          "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tommy351/gists{/gist_id}",
          "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tommy351/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
          "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tommy351/subscriptions",
          "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tommy351/orgs",
          "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tommy351/repos",
          "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tommy351/events{/privacy}",
          "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tommy351/received_events",
          "type": "User",
          "site_admin": false,
          "score": 15.513104
        }
      ]
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCrtl">

<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.login for item in data.items"></select>
<br>Selected Item:{{selectedItem}}
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Shiva ML it's working  as we can see using your exemplo here: http://jsbin.com/powulajesu/edit?output